# Removing gap between Div elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a white space appearing between the two div elements
`col3-2` and `the_content` which I have been unable to resolve.

[image]

[Visit site here](http://www.renttoownyourhomemn.com)
You can see the white gap between the image, and the green element.

HTML - PHP:

```
    <div id="imageslider" class="clearfix">
        <?php echo do_shortcode('[advps-slideshow optset="1"]'); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="col3-2">
            <div id="content" class="clearfix">
                <?php 
                    $args = array( 'pagename' => 'home' );
                    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="the_content">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php edit_post_link(__('Click to edit this content','themify'), '[', ']'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.col3-2
{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.col3-2 {
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
.col3-2 h1 {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size:300%;
}
.the_content{
    display: none;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 0%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in a previous answer, the problem is due to the `p` element in the code snippet:

```
<div id="imageslider" class="clearfix">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col3-2">
    <div id="content" class="clearfix">
        <div class="the_content">
            <p></p> <!--  this causes the problem... -->
            <div id="section1">
                <p></p>
                ...
```

Removing the `p` could solve the problem, but since the content can be edited in the future (Wordpress is the CMS in this case), then the `p` could reappear if the user editing the content inserts an extra carriage return or two in a WYSIWIG inline editing window.

The issue is due to collapsing margins between the `p` (and the containing blocks such as `.the_content`) and `#imageslider`.

A better fix would be to force the `.the_content` block to start a new block formatting context, which can be triggered by using:

```
.the_content { 
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: #17C2A4;
}
```

If you specify the background color on `.the_content` in addition to or instead of on `#section1`, then the background color will extend all the way to the bottom edge of the `#imageslider` block.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in an extraneous `<p>` tag appearing in the `div.the_content` tag:

```
<div class="col3-2">
        <div id="content" class="clearfix">
            <div class="the_content">
                <p></p>
                ...
```

It looks like you're pulling this in from somewhere else, so editing the code you posted probably won't help much. Simply remove the `<p></p>` from the source of the content.

Comment: I just found this as well. Removing the `<p></p>` got rid of the spacing for me.

Comment: And you've got a missing `<div>` with an existing `</div>` and a few more warnings in my editor...